# How to solve the problem that the crawled data is not fully parsed correctly by different encoding formats?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, decode

I am using a Python crawler to crawl data from a website. Here I mainly use `requests` and `etree` to implement the main functions. Firstly,I get the link of the data to be crawled and then traverse each one to get the data I need. Now in the process of decoding the data, no matter what encoding format is used, there is always `UnicodeDecodeError`, (here I use `try/except` statement), that is, there is always data that cannot be decoded.

**Most of the data from most sites can be decoded correctly, but I found that mainly the names of some Japanese movies cannot be decoded very well.**

```
[{'name': '海��の子供/Children  of the Sea', 'category': ['动画','奇幻', '冒险'], 'Score': 6.55},{'name': 'おジャ魔女どれみ  魔女����いをさがして/Looking for Magical  DoReMi', 'category': ['动画', '奇幻'],'Score': 7.1},{'name': '今日から俺は!!���霭�', 'category': ['喜剧'],'Score':7.85}]
```

Of course, the data and the position are different. I would like to get an explanation for this problem and a solution to it. I have been searching for a long time on net. But it is no use. Please help or try to give some ideas or some hint how to achieve this.

The following are some of the URLs where I made errors:

- https://www.dytt8.net/html/gndy/dyzz/20210619/61542.html
- https://www.dytt8.net/html/gndy/dyzz/20210801/61690.html
- https://www.dytt8.net/html/gndy/dyzz/20210328/61255.html

Comment: you shouldn't have to decode anything: `resp.text` is already unicode. can you provide an url where this error occurs?

Comment: I have already used this method at the beginning, and it all comes out garbled. This is a Chinese website.  https://www.dytt8.net/html/gndy/dyzz/20210619/61542.html
  https://www.dytt8.net/html/gndy/dyzz/20210619/61543.html
  https://www.dytt8.net/html/gndy/dyzz/20210618/61539.html                            
I have to do an internship, so there is no way to reply immediately，

Comment: i just passed all three pages with no problem. i assumed you're using `requests` and `lxml`, you should update your first post with the urls and the modules you're using

Comment: Yes，you are right. The main data can indeed be decoded correctly by this method, but the string of the movie name I want cannot be decoded well, especially for Japanese movies. I went back and modified the code again, directly extracting the value of the charset attribute from the web page source code first to compile it.